# What happens if you compose the zeta function with two circle inversion mappings in this specific way?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis, mobius-inversion

Let $I^a_b : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be defined as circle inversion mapping of a circle at the point $a \in \mathbb{C}$ of radius $b = \frac{1}{r}$

What happens to the zero's of the zeta function if you apply the following composition of functions?

$$I^0_2(\zeta(I^0_2(z))$$

In other words, do the various individual zero's of the zeta function get mapped to the same point in the complex plane under this composition, or do they get swapped with their complex conjugate?

Comment: can you clarify exactly what you ask using say the first nontrivial zeta zero say ($1/2+14..i$)? If $z$ in your expression is a non-trivial zero, it lies outside the circle of inversion, so $I^0_2(z)$ is a complex number inside the circle and I see no reason for $\zeta$ to send it to another zeta zero image; maybe I do not get the question though...

Comment: @Conrad Sure.  Consider the first non-trivial zero on the positive part of the imaginary axis, and let's call it $\alpha$, then its complex conjugate is $alpha^*$.  Then my question is does $I^0_2(\zeta(I^0_2(\alpha))=\alpha$ or $\alpha*$  If the answer to this question is YES (because its a statement involving the logical operator OR), then I think this would be pretty significant, because it might be a new idea to start looking at the critical strip from the perspective of circle inversion.

Comment: @Conrad (cont...) let $\gamma(i) = 1 + i$, and let $\gamma(-i) = 1 + i$, then $\gamma$ is symmetric around the real line, and $\gamma$ is invariant under the mapping $i \to -i$.  However, if the complex plane is sitting in a 3d space, and there are little arrows pointing either up or down and attached to the points $i, -i$, then if we do complex conjugate by flipping the entire complex plane over so it lands on itself, there is a measurable difference between $\gamma$ and $\gamma*$.  This idea of turning the complex plane into a 3d coordinate system motivates my question as well.

Comment: Why would be either? Since $I$ is an involution, your claim is that $\zeta$ has the images of its zeroes fixed (or conjugately fixed) under it and I just do not get why is that true. Again I may misunderstand the question but a circle inversion sends the exterior into interior and viceversa; the symmetry in the critical line is not an inversion in a finite circle;

Comment: @Conrad I might be wrong to think $\zeta$ has its zeroes fixed.  What I had in mind was that under $I^0_2$ the line $Im(z)=1/2$ is mapped to a circle inside the circle of inversion, and vice versa.  So if all the zeroes of $\zeta$ lie on the critical line, then I thought they would be fixed under the composition $I^0_2 \cdot \zeta \cdot I^0_2(z)$.  First the critical line is mapped to a circle inside the circle of inversion, then zeta happens, then the circle is mapped back to the line.  And the singularity of zeta at $z=1$ is mapped to zero by $I^0_2$.  Is this wrong?

Comment: why does zeta maps that circle to itself? for example, zeta maps the critical line to a highly complicated plane set (assumed to be dense thought not yet proved; however vertical lines between $1/2$ and $1$ are mapped to dense plane sets

Comment: @Conrad good question.  I am thinking about this picture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry#/media/File:Inv-stereogr-proj.svg  Under $I^0_2$, all the points on the critical line  get mapped to all the points on the circle it gets mapped to, except the point at infinity which is mapped to 0, and vice versa.  Since $I^0_2$ is an involution, then it maps the points on the image of the critical line under this mapping, back to the critical line.  This makes sense to me, could you maybe elaborate on which part doesn't make sense?

Comment: You introduce $\zeta(w)=y$ for $w$ the image of a zero under the involution; there is no reason that i see that $y$ must be on the circle where $w$ lived (the image  of the critical  line under the involution) ; zeta in the critical strip is a highly complicated function, so the image of that circle can be anything, especially that infinity is mapped to zero on the circle and  zeta has an essential  singularity at infinity, so zeta composed with the convolution will have one such  at zero and in particular the image of the circle won't  be compact